# Error parse json for retrofit 2, expected begin array but was begin object

Tags: java, android, gson, retrofit2

Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path

My interface looks like this

```
public interface UsersApi {
   @GET("/api/?results=20")
   Call<List<Result>> getData();
}
```

Json API

```
{
   "results": [
      {
         "gender":"female",
         "name":{
            "title":"Miss",
            "first":"Lana",
            "last":"Da Silva"
            }
      }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Please post your `Result` POJO

Comment: Here is my POJO class, posted on pastebin as it contains 80+ lines
https://pastebin.com/vXSvejEp

Comment: You using retrofit? Can you post the initialization

Comment: similarly as I do it in cauldrons, but in it there is no error and in java is

https://pastebin.com/v5TUP6gM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please Create modal Class like below e.g.

```
public class Modal {

@SerializedName("results")
private List<Result> mResults;

public List<Result> getResults() {
    return mResults;
}

public void setResults(List<Result> results) {
    mResults = results;
}

}



public interface UsersApi {
@GET("/api/?results=20")
Call<Modal> getData();
}
```

Comment: I really don't see how that is going to help when then Retrofit documentation advocates the way @stepan has done it 

https://square.github.io/retrofit/

Comment: you can use Call<List<Repo>>   if your response start from jsonArray in your case Your response satart from JsonObject.

Your response: {
   "results": [
      {
         "gender":"female",
         "name":{
            "title":"Miss",
            "first":"Lana",
            "last":"Da Silva"
      }
     }
    ]
}

Required response :[
      {
         "gender":"female",
         "name":{
            "title":"Miss",
            "first":"Lana",
            "last":"Da Silva"
      }
     }
    ]

Comment: apologies I see what you mean now!